# Catching an element by class name and adding innerHTML to it

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementsbyclassname

I have had trouble getting hold of my elements class name. Now that I finally managed to do so, I do not seem to be able to add innerHTML to it.

I am adding an quote within an existing element. This is how I managed to get the class name as no other way of getElementsByClassName did not work:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('name-of-element');
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) { 

}
```

I tried combining the two scripts I have like so:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('name-of-element');
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) { 
  elements.innerHTML = 'the change I am trying to make';

}
```

I tried changing the "elements" of "elements.innerHTML" but have not figured out anything that would work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you properly format your code pls?

Comment: just add elements[i].innerHTML

Comment: access each element by the index `elements[i].innerHTML = 'the change I am trying to make';` inside your loop. Remember that the method `getElementsByClassName` returns an array like object

Comment: Thank you all, this did it! Frustrating that I was so close and yet so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use elements[i] in your loop, it's not working because you're trying to change the innerhtml of the html collection rather than of the individual elements inside it.

Remember that **getElementsByClassName** (plural elements) returns an array-like object called a html collection.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('name-of-element');

for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].innerHTML = 'the change I am trying to make';
}
```

```html
<div class='name-of-element'></div>
<div class='name-of-element'></div>
<div class='name-of-element'></div>
<div class='name-of-element'></div>
<div class='name-of-element'></div>
```